# Offline and Online syncing with Web applications in HTML5?

Tags: mysql, html, sqlite, transactions, synchronization

I have a basic web application below that has a sqlite storage measure implemented into it.

I would like it to be able to update my mysql server anytime it is connected, and store values to push to the database after it has lost connection. I would like it to be able to
use a timestamp comparison as a safety measure, just in case values on the server differ, we can to a stamp check to see if what it is trying to alter IS the most current values.
(this will be run from multiple computers, so will need SOME kind of failsafe).

I believe that this transaction WILL only need to be one way though, the values just need to update the server, values will not need to be passed back to the application, so we could technically destroy the database upon a real completion, or possibly perform a rollback if it breaks somewhere. Is this a doable thing, or am I really asking to much here?

Here's a very basic app I'd like to use as a model.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>  
  <head>
    <title>Golf score keeper</title>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script>
      google.load("jquery", "1.4.1");
    </script>
    <script>
      var db = window.openDatabase("scores", "", "Previous Scores", 1024*1000);

      function insertScore(hole_num, num_strokes, course_id, email) {
       db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Strokes (course_id, hole_num, num_strokes, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', [course_id, hole_num, num_strokes, email]);
       });
      }

      function renderResults(tx, rs) {
    e = $('#previous_scores');
    e.html("");
    for(var i=0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) {
      r = rs.rows.item(i);
      e.html(e.html() + 'id: ' + r['id'] + ', hole_num: ' + r['hole_num'] + ', num_strokes: ' + r['num_strokes'] + ', email: ' + r['email'] + '<br />');
    }
      }

      function renderScores(email) {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      if (!(email === undefined)) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Strokes WHERE email = ?', [email], renderResults);
      } else {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Strokes', [], renderResults);
      }
    });
      }

      $(document).ready(function() {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Courses(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, latitude FLOAT, longitude FLOAT)', []);
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Strokes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, course_id INTEGER, hole_num INTEGER, num_strokes INTEGER, email TEXT)', []);
    });

    $('#score_form').submit(function() {
     strokes = { 1: $('#hole1').val(), 2: $('#hole2').val() };
      for (var hole_num in strokes) {
        insertScore(hole_num, strokes[hole_num], 1, $('#email').val());
      }

      renderScores();
      return false;
    });

    $('#filter_previous_scores_form').submit(function() {
      e = $('#filter_by_email').val();
      renderScores(e);
      return false;
    });

    renderScores();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="get" id="score_form">
      <div>
    <label for="1">Hole 1</label>
    <input type="number" min="1" value="4" id="hole1" name="hole1" size="2" step="1" />
      </div>
      <div>
    <label for="2">Hole 2</label>
    <input type="number" min="1" value="4" id="hole1" name="hole2" size="2" step="1" />
      </div>
      <div>
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" size="40"/>
      </div>
      <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Score" />
      </div>
    </form>
    <div>
      <h2>Previous Scores</h2>
      <form id="filter_previous_scores_form">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Filter scores by email" size="40" id="filter_by_email" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="previous_scores">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoulg take a look at [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) in a `setInterval` loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can apply the logic of set interval when you found navigator.online=true then you can call ajax.